# SQL Performance Reports - but for a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sqlperformance

SQL Server comes with very handy "performance" reports: in SSMS - right-click the server - "reporting" - "Standard" - you see many useful reports, like "Top queries by Total CPU time", "Top queries by average I/O" etc.

These reports aggregate the data since last restart or since last query stats reset.

Is there any way to see these reports **for a date range**? Like "Top queries by total CPU time from 10pm to 11pm"? Maybe there's an SQL Server addon on or service that should be installed or something, that would allow this kind or research?

Real life use case: a DBA wakes up and sees there were some "timeout" errors during the night. He wants to see which queries were running at the moment and eating up performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this series of blog posts at SQLShack that advises installing "Data Collectors" that continuously record performance data, so you can analyse it later: [SQL Server performance monitoring with Data Collector](http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-performance-monitoring-data-collector-part-2-set-up-and-usage/)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the SSMS Performance Dashboard Reports from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29063) and use as Custom reports with SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014. Having access to the rdl file you can customize it however you want.

Also worth reading [this](http://www.sqlshack.com/performance-dashboard-reports-sql-server-2014/).

Comment: While this article is useful indeed, the reports show **current** performance data. SQL Server does not store perfomance **history** be default.